# Randomize when something happens

Tags: java, math, if-statement, random, double

I have implemented a power up in my game and I want it to have an 10% chance to apply to the player when it kills a zombie. I have tried using this code every time the players bullet hits an zombie, but it doesn't really work.

```
double rand = Math.random() * 10 + 1;
if(rand == 1){
    power.setShrink(true);
}
```

I know that the power-ups work because if I set it outside of the if-statement the player will get shrunk.

How would I make it so that it's an 10% chance for the effect to apply the player when a zombie get killed?

Comment: it is a very low possibility that _rand_ will hit 1. check if it is in some interval, that's better.

Comment: @Juvanis I have also tried `double rand = Math.random() * 1 + 1;` and that didn't work either.

Comment: The real problem of your code is comparing a double with an int. Java will convert the int to double rather then double. So,  1.0001 will not equals to 1.0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubles are floating point numbers. In you case, it can be any number from 1 to 11, up to around 53 binary digits of precision. So not only can it be 1, it can also be 1.01, 1.02, etc. Te odds of it being exactly 1 are therefore negligible.

You're better off with `Random.nextInt` when generating random integers.

```
Random r = new Random(); //only do this once

if(r.nextInt(10) == 0){
    power.setShrink(true);
}
```

Comment: Correct in principle, but your example suggests nextInt is a static method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [Monte-Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) selection:

```
if(Math.random() > 0.9){
   power.setShrink(true);
}
```

This gives you a random chance of the possibility 1 of 10 that it will trigger the power-up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Random.nextInt(10)` in a similar piece of logic.

Your current code is failing because your `double` is very rarely going to be exactly `1`.